# Need audio web player plays all audio formats

Tags: flash, audio

I need a audio web player that plays all kind of audio files such as wav,mp3,dct,au,aiff,wma,aac,ogg,etc., I tried lot of free players found on the web. But no one of them are playing the files other than mp3 and rarely ogg. I also tried converting other formats to mp3 using ffmpeg, but still players are not playing the converted files. Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: sounds like you need google more than stackoverflow

Comment: Hi Neil, I googled this for several hrs but didn't get any players for my requirements.

Comment: I doubt you would find one player to play all of those different formats, this is one of the problems with codecs. Hope you get some help on stackoverflow, good luck.